# Refreshing the workbench

Tags: eclipse-rcp

HI,

I am facing some problem.. I want to hide the menu when eclipse workbench starts.
But the problem is menu is not hiding when the eclipse workbench starts. It is hiding only
when some refresh is happened. for example: when I change the default perspective to some other perspective, I am getting the desired out put. That means menu is hiding.
But when the eclipse workbench is loaded it is not hiding the menu. Below is my code.

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
IWorkbenchWindow window = Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
if(window instanceof WorkbenchWindow) {
   MenuManager menuManager = ((WorkbenchWindow)window).getMenuManager();
IContributionItem[] items = menuManager.getItems();
           for(IContributionItem item:items){
                  System.out.println("item.getId()::: "+item.getId());
                  menuManager.remove("org.eclipse.ui.run");
                  menuManager.remove("help");
                  menuManager.remove("project");
           }
   }
}`
}
};
```

Comment: I guess my first question is...why do you want to do this?  Are you trying to hide certain features?  Getting a better idea of what you want to do will help determine the best way to do it.

Comment: Yaa exactly.. I need to hide some features..

Comment: your code must be overrided by Eclipse's code

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are looking to hide some features, I don't think that this is the best approach.  (Not I am using the term *feature* here in the colloquial way, not as an *Eclipse feature*.

I would recommend one of two avenues:

1. Perspectives: See the extension point org.eclipse.ui.perspectives.  This allows you to create a new perspective like the debug perspective or the Java perspective.  Using a perspective, you can select exactly what menu items and views are shown and which ones are hidden.
2. Capabilities (aka activites): See the extension point org.eclipse.ui.activities.  This allows you to have some fairly fine-grained control over what features are available in the workspace.  See more info here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Galileo_Capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Put Your code in org.eclipse.ui.startup extention point. Make a Startup class after implementing the interface IStartup. For Details follow this link:-
[Eclipse plugin : disable/enable dynamically an action from main menubar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571372/eclipse-plugin-disable-enable-dynamically-an-action-from-main-menubar)